# return false in AJAX call disabling php update

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following script that I was having issues with the `$("#success")` to fadeout and delay. I thought I figured it out, but when I have the `return false;` not commented out, my php script doesn't work. When it is commented out my ajax call works and the php file does what it is supposed to do, but the fadeout and delay doesn't work.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.approve').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
           url: 'userRequest_approve.php',
           type: 'POST',
           data: {
            id: $(this).val(), //id
            status: 'Approved' //status
           },
           success: function(data) {
            //do something with the data that got returned
             $("#success").fadeIn();
                 $("#success").show();
                 $('#success').html('User Status Changed!');
                 $('#success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
           },
           //type: 'POST'
        });
    //return false;
    });
    });
</script>
```

UPDATE: SOURCE CODE ADDED FROM THE FORM

```
    <form action="" method="POST" id="status">
             <input type='hidden' name='id' value='33' id='pending_id'/>
Name - hgfd hgd</br>Username - testttttt</br></br>      </form>

                        <button class="approve" type="submit" form="status" name="approve" value="33">Approve</button>
                        <button id="deny" type="submit" form="status" name="deny" value="Denied">Deny</button><br><br><br>
        <form action="" method="POST" id="status">
             <input type='hidden' name='id' value='23' id='pending_id'/>
Name - boo boo</br>Username - boopbfd</br></br>     </form>
```

Comment: Why do you want to return false at the end? It's not stopping any part of the script. Do you see any response of the PHP script in the console?

Comment: most likely when you remove it a form is being submitted using default browser submit process and reloading page...what is `$('.approve')`?

Comment: I was told I had to have the return false there so the form wasn't submitted, but I need the form to submit so my php code works. With that line commented out the code works perfect other than the fadeout delay. It is like once the results from the php script come in the #success message goes away,

Comment: leave the `return false` in then or use `event.preventDefault()` and debug the ajax request itself. Can inspect requests in network tab of browser dev tools. Possibly path is bad or not sending correct data like `id: $(this).val()` looks suspicious. SHow us the `$('.approve')` html. If php is throwing a 500 error or 404 `success` won't be called

Comment: @Paul If you need the form to be submitted **after** the `fadeOut`, just do `.fadeOut(function(){ $('#myForm').submit(); },400)` where `#myForm` is the ID of your form. And leave the `return false;` uncommented so that it does not submit immediately.

Comment: I want the fadeout to appear after the php script has ran and it was successful and then for the fadeout message to show

Comment: @charlietfl I added the source code for the form.

Answer (score -1):

You need to wait for the response from the server using a promise. This will "await" the response from your server code then execute the code "after" the response is returned from the server.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.approve').click(function(){
    var promise = $.ajax({
       url: 'userRequest_approve.php',
       type: 'POST',
       data: {
        id: $(this).val(), //id
        status: 'Approved' //status
       }
    });

    promise.then(function(data){
        $("#success").fadeIn();
             $("#success").show();
             $('#success').html('User Status Changed!');
             $('#success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
    });
});
```

});

Comment: although deprecated, that's what the `success` callback does already

Comment: Think of it this way, when you make your call to the server using $ajax the call is made but your javascript code after the code continues to run unless you wait for the response first and then continue doing what you want to do after.

Comment: @charlietfl That is not what success does. Success fires off on success, that is all. If the server takes a while to send a response the code in the success can happen after you want it to (after the code beyond the ajax call is called). Using a promise is like calling an async method and a "then" is like an "await".

Comment: you have a complete misunderstanding of $.ajax api. It has a `done` method already based on promise also and `success` won't fire if response isn't returned or has parse problem or status isn't 200

Comment: I have a perfect understanding of the ajax api. Using success or done will return on a 200. Write some server call that sleeps for a few seconds and add some code after you success or done function and it will fire off before it is "done". Using a promise ensures you can await the server response "before" doing anything else if you chose.

Comment: OP obviously isn't getting proper response which is the underlying issue regardless of how you manipulate the promise

Comment: This did not resolve the issue. This runs my php update query and performs what I want that to do, but still the issue remains that my 'success' message goes away right after the php query has ran. I need the success message to remain on the page after everything has ran for the duration of time I have it set to.